# ImportError: libSpinnaker.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: python-3.x

Por favor que estoy haciendo mal no entiendo... alguien me puede ayudar?

este es el cod:

```
qm1@qm1-System-Product-Name:~/Escritorio/proyectos$ /usr/bin/python /home/qm1/Escritorio/proyectos/Acquisition.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/qm1/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PySpin.py", line 14, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module(mname)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 658, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 571, in module_from_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 922, in create_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
ImportError: libSpinnaker.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Bienvenido a **StackOverflow** , te recomiendo que realices el [Recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y asi obtengas tu primera medalla, ademas mira [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para asi poder ayudarte mejor.

Comment: Danos más información, qué código has escrito? qué estás intentando hacer?, etc...

Comment: I have exactly the same problem with python 3.7 , did you manage to fix this?